# calculate 2d array with reduce in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, multidimensional-array

In Vue, I'm inserting a value in a 2d array input field and calculating it per row, but the total value that is being returned only calculates the first row, and when I display, the computed value is all the same.

How can i calculate the inputted value so that the value will  compute it per row and not just the first value?

This is what i get:
[sample image of the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JRWB.jpg)

FIDDLE:[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pailaka/ntbzp5m0/)

```
NAME   | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | TOTAL
name1  |   1    |   1    | 2
name2  |   2    |   3    | 2
name3  |        |        | 2
```

**script**

```
 data() {
    return {
      form: new Form({
        labStudentScores: [],
      })
    };
  },
 computed: {
    studentTotalScore: function() {
      return this.form.labStudentScores.reduce(
        (acc, item) => acc + parseInt(item.value),
        0
      );
    },
methods: {
 addScore: function() {
      this.form.labStudentScores.push({ value: [] });
    }
}
```

**Template**

```
<button type="button" @click="addScore">score(+)</button>

//classlists is comming from http request
 <tr v-for="(classlist,index) in classlists" :key="'lab'+ classlist.id">
    <td>{{index +1}}</td>
    <td>
        {{classlist.student}}
    </td>
    <td v-for="(labStudentScore,i) in form.labStudentScores" :key="i">
        <input v-model="labStudentScore.value[index]"  />
    </td>

    <td>{{studentTotalScore}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computed variable is really only one number `studentTotalScore`. Since you want a number for each row, this computed value should be an array `studentTotalScores`. Each row should have its own index.

```
this.form.labStudentScores[index].push(value);
```

And in your template you should also refer to the correct row too for calulation.

```
{{studentTotalScore[index]}}
```

Of course your compute function should also only compute values of the related row.

Comment: tnx for replying.
 i'm gonna change
`methods: addScore with "this.form.labStudentScores[index].push(value);"?`

Comment: this is giving me an error ` "this.form.labStudentScores[index] is undefined"`

Comment: your starting point is: your computed value studentTotalScores has to be an array. afterwards you have to adjust everything to work with that array. so yes, addScore has to add scores to an array within the array. first dimension is which person gets the score and second dimension is the multiple score for that single person.